# JDK 1.3 : The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 1 (""): Data type 0x38 is unknown

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I am using JDK 1.3 and jtds-1.2.7.jar to connect to SQL Server 2008 server.
The connection is created successfully, but when executing a stored procedure I'm getting the following exception.

> The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC)
>   protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 1 (""): Data type 0x38 is
>   unknown

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I just have to ask ... why JDK 1.3?

Comment: It is a product, we dont have source code. It is running only in JDK 1.3 as it is using JRun 3 version.

Comment: Are you positive jtds-1.2.7 can run on JDK 1.3? It's a fairly recent implementation.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that too. But with no success.

Comment: According to the [JTDS 1.2.7 releasenotes](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/jtds/1.2.7/release%20notes.txt/download) it is Java 1.3 compatible. The problem might actually be one of driver compatibility: [this Micrsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/915834) describes the same error, but when using the SQL Server 2000 driver to connect to SQL Server 2005. As it is the exact same error: are you sure you are actually using JTDS?